# Ruby enumerator chaining

Tags: ruby, list, enumerator

In this example,

```
[1, 2, 3].each_with_index.map{|i, j| i * j}
# => [0, 2, 6]
```

my understanding is that, since `each_with_index` enumerator is chained to `map`, `map` behaves like `each_with_index` by passing an index inside the block, and returns a new array.

For this,

```
[1, 2, 3].map.each_with_index{|i, j| i * j}
# => [0, 2, 6]
```

I'm not sure how to I interpret it.

In this example,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map.find {|i| i == 2}
# => 2
```

I was expecting the the output to be `[2]`, assuming that `map` is chained to `find`, and `map` would return a new array.

Also, I see this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].find.each_with_object([]){|i, j| j.push(i)}
# => [1]

[1, 2, 3, 4].each_with_object([]).find{|i, j| i == 3}
# => [3, []]
```

Can you let me know how to interpret and understand enumerator chains in Ruby?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might find it useful to break these expressions down and use IRB or PRY to see what Ruby is doing.  Let's start with:

```
[1,2,3].each_with_index.map { |i,j| i*j }
```

Let

```
enum1 = [1,2,3].each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each_with_index>
```

We can use [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) (or [Enumerable#entries](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries)) to convert `enum1` to an array to see what it will be passing to the next enumerator (or to a block if it had one):

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
```

No surprise there.  But `enum1` does not have a block.  Instead we are sending it the method [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
enum2 = enum1.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:each_with_index>:map>
```

You might think of this as a sort of "compound" enumerator.  This enumerator does have a block, so converting it to an array will confirm that it will pass the same elements into the block as `enum1` would have:

```
enum2.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
```

We see that the array `[1,0]` is the first element `enum2` passes into the block.  "Disambiguation" is applied to this array to assign the block variables the values:

```
i => 1
j => 0
```

That is, Ruby is setting:

```
i,j = [1,0]
```

We now can invoke `enum2` by sending it the method `each` with the block:

```
enum2.each { |i,j| i*j }
  #=> [0, 2, 6]
```

Next consider:

```
[1,2,3].map.each_with_index { |i,j| i*j }
```

We have:

```
enum3 = [1,2,3].map
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>
enum3.to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
enum4 = enum3.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>:each_with_index>
enum4.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
enum4.each { |i,j| i*j }
  #=> [0, 2, 6]
```

Since `enum2` and `enum4` pass the same elements into the block, we see this is just two ways of doing the same thing.

Here's a third equivalent chain:

```
[1,2,3].map.with_index { |i,j| i*j }
```

We have:

```
enum3 = [1,2,3].map
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>
enum3.to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
enum5 = enum3.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>:with_index>
enum5.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
enum5.each { |i,j| i*j }
  #=> [0, 2, 6]
```

To take this one step further, suppose we had:

```
[1,2,3].select.with_index.with_object({}) { |(i,j),h| ... }
```

We have:

```
enum6 = [1,2,3].select
  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:select>
enum6.to_a
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
enum7 = enum6.with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:select>:with_index>
enum7.to_a
  #=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
enum8 = enum7.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:
  #     select>:with_index>:with_object({})>
enum8.to_a
  #=> [[[1, 0], {}], [[2, 1], {}], [[3, 2], {}]]
```

The first element `enum8` passes into the block is the array:

```
(i,j),h = [[1, 0], {}]
```

Disambiguation is then applied to assign values to the block variables:

```
i => 1
j => 0
h => {}
```

Note that `enum8` shows an empty hash being passed in each of the three elements of `enum8.to_a`, but of course that's only because Ruby doesn't know what the hash will look like after the first element is passed in.

Comment: very well put forward

Answer (score 1):

Methods you are mentioning are defined on `Enumerable` objects. These methods behave differently depending on whether you pass a block or not.

- When you do not pass a block, they typically return **an `Enumerator` object**, to which you can chain further methods like `each_with_index`, `with_index`, `map`, etc.
- When you pass a block to these methods, they return **different kinds of object** depending on what will make sense for that particular method.

  - For methods like `find`, its purpose is to find the first object that satisfies a condition, and it does not make particular sense to wrap that in an array, so it returns that object bare.
  - For methods like `select` or `reject`, their purpose is to return all relevant objects, so they cannot return a single object, and they have to be wrapped in an array (even when the relevant object happens to be a single object).

Comment: I got that point but how do you interpret the chain like i said above `[1,2,3].each_with_index.map { |i,j| i*j }` and  `[1,2,3].map.each_with_index { |i,j| i*j }` return exactly same result what am I suppose to believe then