# How does Ruby Enumerators chaining work exactly?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

Consider the following code:

```rb
[1,2,3].map.with_index { |x, i| x * i }
# => [0,2,6]
```

How does this work exactly?

My mental model of `map` is that it iterates and apply a function on each element. Is `with_index` somehow passing a function to the enumerator `[1,2,3].map`, in which case what would that function be?

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199928/ruby-enumerator-chaining) shows how enumerators pass data through, but doesn't answer the question. Indeed, if you replace `map` with `each` then the behaviour is different:

```rb
[1,2,3].each.with_index { |x, i| x * i }
# => [1,2,3]
```

`map` seems to carry the information that a function has to be applied, on top of carrying the data to iterate over. How does that work?

Comment: I associate the words "Enumerator chaining` with code like `c = [1,2,3].chain([4,5,6])`. "Method chaining" is the more usual term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todd's answer is excellent, but I feel like seeing some more Ruby code might be beneficial. Specifically, let's try to *write* `each` and `map` on `Array` ourselves.

I won't use any `Enumerable` or `Enumerator` methods directly, so we see how it's all working under the hood (I'll still use `for` loops, and those technically call `#each` under the hood, but that's only cheating a little)

First, there's `each`. `each` is easy. It iterates over the array and applies a function to each element, before returning the *original* array.

```
def my_each(arr, &block)
  for i in 0..arr.length-1
    block[arr[i]]
  end
  arr
end
```

Simple enough. Now what if we don't pass a block. Let's change it up a bit to support that. We effectively want to *delay* the act of doing the `each` to allow the `Enumerator` to do its thing

```
def my_each(arr, &block)
  if block
    for i in 0..arr.length-1
      block[arr[i]]
    end
    arr
  else
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      my_each(arr) { |*x| y.yield(*x) }
    end
  end
end
```

So if we don't pass a block, we make an `Enumerator` that, when consumed, calls `my_each`, using the enumerator yield object as a block. The `y` object is a funny thing but you can just think of it as basically being the block you'll eventually pass in. So, in

```
my_each([1, 2, 3]).with_index { |x, i| x * i }
```

Think of `y` as being like the `{ |x, i| x * i }` bit. It's a bit more complicated than that, but that's the idea.

Incidentally, on Ruby 2.7 and later, the `Enumerator::Yielder` object got its own `#to_proc`, so if you're on a recent Ruby version, you can just do

```
Enumerator.new do |y|
  my_each(arr, &y)
end
```

rather than

```
Enumerator.new do |y|
  my_each(arr) { |*x| y.yield(*x) }
end
```

Now let's extend this approach to `map`. Writing `map` with a block is easy. It's just like `each` but we accumulate the results.

```
def my_map(arr, &block)
  result = []
  for i in 0..arr.length-1
    result << block[arr[i]]
  end
  result
end
```

Simple enough. Now what if we don't pass a block? Let's do the *exact* same thing we did for `my_each`. That is, we're just going to make an `Enumerator` and, inside that `Enumerator`, we call `my_map`.

```
def my_map(arr, &block)
  if block
    result = []
    for i in 0..arr.length-1
      result << block[arr[i]]
    end
    result
  else
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      my_map(arr) { |*x| y.yield(*x) }
    end
  end
end
```

Now, the `Enumerator` knows that, whenever it eventually gets a block, it's going to use `my_map` on that block at the end. We can see that these two functions actually behave, on arrays, like `map` and `each` do

```
my_each([1, 2, 3]).with_index { |x, i| x * i } # [1, 2, 3]
my_map ([1, 2, 3]).with_index { |x, i| x * i } # [0, 2, 6]
```

So your intuition was spot on

> `map` seems to carry the information that a function has to be applied, on top of carrying the data to iterate over. How does that work?

That's exactly what it does. `map` creates an `Enumerator` whose block knows to call `map` at the end, whereas `each` does the same but with `each`. Of course, in reality, all of this is implemented in C for efficiency and bootstrapping reasons, but the fundamental idea is still there.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-map) without a block simply returns an Enumerator, where each element is then fed to [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) and the results of the block are returned as a collection. It's not complicated, and is similar to (but perhaps cleaner than) the following code. Using Ruby 3.0.1:

```
results = []
[1, 2, 3].each_with_index { results << _1 * _2 }
results
#=> [0, 2, 6]
```

Using [Array#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-each) doesn't return a collection from the block. It just returns self or another enumerator, so the expected behavior is different by design.

Comment: `Array#each` can't return anything anyway as it's not in the last position in the chain, right? Sorry I still don't understand how `map` and `each` can influence the overall expression since the last item is `with_index`.
Another way to put it is to consider `[1,2,3].filter.with_index {|x, i| i == 2}` Somehow, the block now makes filtering. How is the block connected to `filter` in the expression?

Comment: @JonathanBoccara You're thinking about this wrong. Almost everything in Ruby forms or returns an expression, and that expression returns a value. It just so happens that some values are collections, literals, or enumerators. You need to look at the definitions of each method, and see what they return (which is sometimes dependent on form, e.g. block vs. argument) to understand how they differ. The differences *are* documented, though.

Comment: Yeah I definitely have a wrong mental model  . So IIUC `with_index` sort of calls the iteration behaviour of `map` with a function that yields the block `with_index` receives?
And if you consider `[1,2,3].filter.map { |x| x * 2 }`, the behaviour of the `filter` enumerator is never invoked?

Comment: My guess in that case is that `map` is an `Enumerable` method, so you're effectively ignoring the `Enumerator` aspect of the object and just performing a calculation on the underlying data. `with_index` is an `Enumerator` method, which understands how to interact with the original enumerator block. If you do `[1, 2, 3].filter.with_index { ... }` then the `filter` still gets run. Although I've frankly never seen that pattern of `.filter.map { ... }` used before, so I'm not completely sure what it means. There may be some subtlety I'm missing.

Comment: @JonathanBoccara Everyone's brain works a little differently. :) I think your last sentence is spot on: `[1,2,3].filter.class #=> Enumerator`, so essentially the filter method in `[1,2,3].filter.map { |x| x * 2 }` just yields the original Array as an Enumerator. Since there's no block argument to #filter, all it does is pass an Enumerator object on to Enumerable#map, which then applies its own block.